# AC_ARG_ENABLE fails on TCL

Tags: gcc, tcl, autoconf

I execute the following code on AIX box using TCL and it fails

The reason for failure is that somehow 'gcc' is ENABLED by DEFAULT on that AIX LPAR.

I want to DISABLE gcc.  How can I do that?

```
AC_DEFUN(SC_ENABLE_GCC, [
    AC_ARG_ENABLE(gcc, [  --enable-gcc            allow use of gcc if available [--disable-gcc]],
        [ok=$enableval], [ok=no])
    if test "$ok" = "yes"; then
        CC=gcc
        AC_PROG_CC
    else
        CC=${CC-cc}
    fi
])
```

Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do two things:

1. Specify the `--disable-gcc` option to `configure`.
2. Set the exported `CC` environment variable to the compiler you actually want to use prior to running `configure`.

This might be combined into:

```
CC=cc ./configure --disable-gcc ...
```

(I commonly have my `CC` variable set to a `clang` variant on my platform…)